# I need help identifying a feature

Tags: buttons

I have been using an app called Foodpanda that is able to show a button on top of other apps and, on the home screen.

It makes this little button which I have marked in the screenshots below with an arrow. Observations:

1. The app does not have any special permissions
2. The button appears only when a support chat is active on the app
3. The button takes me into that view and disappears when that view is active.
4. The button cannot be hidden if there is a chat active in the background.

> **What is this feature/functionality called? Is there a way to disallow it?**

[image: Screenshots]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the feature is `Draw over other apps`. Funnily, ***this is not a permission that needs to be granted***.

I've confirmed this. When I disable that permission, the app cannot draw that button.

Also, it is a long way down from the other permissions.

[image]

Comment: Another interesting thing I found is that it cannot show anything on the permission screens- both the general permission and the advanced one for drawing on other apps.